# Pass userform control to sub

Tags: vba, excel

I've got two subs: cmdSafe and checkTime. I want to call subCheck and pass a userform control.

```
Private Sub cmdSafe_click()
    Call checkTime(ufTimes.txtBegin)
End Sub

Sub checkTime(cntrl as Control)
    'Do something
End sub
```

In this case, I'm getting an error when it tries to call the sub. `Run-time error 424: Object required.`
I went to check ufTimes.txtBegin, but this gives the value of the textbox, `15`.

I hoped to be able to solve this by changing the first sub to the following:

```
Private Sub cmdSafe_click()
    Dim ctl as control
    ctl = ufTimes.txtBegin

    Call checkTime(ufTimes.txtBegin)
End Sub
```

This gave me another error (`Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block not set`) on the line `ctl=ufTimes.txtBegin`, probably because it's trying to set ctl to be a value. How do I solve this? I want to pass a control through, and it should also be able to be a ComboBox for example

Comment: Try setting it as an MSForms.Control or MSForms.Textbox.

Comment: Same problem. I don't think that's weird because the line `ctl =  ufTimes.txtBegin` is interpreted as `control = "15"`

Comment: Is `ufTimes` your `UserForm` or your `TextBox`?  It's the `UserForm`, right?  What version of Excel?

Comment: try : `Set ctl = ufTimes.txtBegin`.

Comment: @cxw this ufTimes is indeed the `Userform`, `txtBegin` is the `textbox`.

Comment: Try `Call CheckTwoNumbers(ufTimes.Controls("cntrl"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2013, the equivalent seems to work fine — (**edit**) provided you use `Set` when assigning `Control` variables.  I added a CommandButton and a TextBox to a blank userform, with code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim c As Control
    Set c = TextBox1                      '<-- works with "Set"
    Call DoSomething(UserForm1.TextBox1)  '<-- also works
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(c As Control)
    MsgBox c.Text
End Sub
```

One option would be to use `TextBox` instead of `Control` - be more specific if you can.

I have references set to VBA, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library, and Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library.